# HTML 5 video not looping in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I have used video tag in my code and and have given loop="loop" for the video to loop it is working fine in firefox but in chrome the video is not looping.
 Here is the code.

```
<video id="bgvid" loop="loop" autoplay muted>
    <source src="../videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="../videos/video1.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

I even tried it with javascript but that also did not work

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById('bgvid');
myVideo.loop = true;
```

Comment: Your code works for me in chrome v. 37. http://jsfiddle.net/1gxuqntr/

Comment: But it is not happening for me. I also have version 37

Comment: what is your video resolution?

Comment: try giving `loop` next to muted instead giving as a attribute

Comment: i tried giving loop after muted it didnt work. video resolution is 1280*720